# How to replace framelayout with fragment programmatically

Tags: android, android-framelayout, fragmenttransaction

I am trying to replace a framelayout with id container by a fragment when a button is clicked in an activity. I think the code I've written is working but something is not right may be it's the layout issue. When the app runs, the fragment appears for blink of a second and it fades right away,somethings blocking it. May be the framelayout is having issue with viewpager. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my xml.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Skip"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/txt_skip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            app:centered="true"
            app:fillColor="@color/white"
            app:pageColor="@color/white"
            app:snap="false"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            />


        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/primary_color"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/primary_color"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <fragment
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.app.foodmandu.view.nav.NavigationDrawerFragment"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This the method that triggers the fragment transaction from an activity when a button is clicked.

```
// inside onClick method.
 openFragment( SignupFragment.newInstance());


// This method gets invoked when a button is clicked.
 public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container,
            fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Comment: things aren't looking very promising the way frame layout has got it's children views

Comment: @PankajNimgade any suggestion on what should i do to get this thing working?

Comment: I believe you might run into the conflict between ViewPager and Framelayout as you can have fragments for both of them, you might what to think the design flow for the application first

Comment: post code of your fragment i.e. SignupFragment

Comment: @KapilRajput I am pretty sure there is nothing to do with  the signup fragment.The code is working but views are conflicting

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the default fragment on the activity **onCreate** method like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, YOUR FRAGMENT).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your FrameLayout gets hidden under ViewPager and ViewPager is overlapping the FrameLayout. Try this one :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/txt_skip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:centered="true"
        app:fillColor="@color/white"
        app:pageColor="@color/white"
        app:snap="false"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        />


    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>


<fragment
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.app.foodmandu.view.nav.NavigationDrawerFragment"/>
```

By putting your FrameLayout at the last inside RelativeLayout , it will appear on top of everything and will overlap any other view.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but viewpager blocks the framelayout.